# Identify names with no match on another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two sheets that contain mostly identical names but a few names with no match on the other sheet. For example:

Sheet 1

```
1. Kumar
2. Rajiv
3. Ranjith
4. Supriya
5. Sanjay
```

Sheet 2

```
1. Kumar
2. Rajiv
3. Ranjith
4. Hari
5. Sanjay
6. Supriya
```

I need to identify `Hari` as not having a match on Sheet 1.

How can I identify such names that appear on Sheet 2 but not on Sheet 1?

Comment: Hi user606112. Please note that Super User is not a script writing service. However, if you show us what you have done and what exactly you are having trouble with, we will probably be happy to help you out. Please [edit] your question to add more detail on exactly what you want us to tell you. For more information on this, please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

In *Sheet2*, cell **B1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0)),"mismatch","")
```

and copy down:

[image]

you can perform this type of method for *Sheet1* if desired.